# Display right text color according to selection?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I like to change text color to `green` for an event, if `eventStatus = 1`,   and `red` if the `eventStatus = 2`. I tried the following and it is changing `every event` to `green` if the `last selected` `eventStatus = 1` and `every event` to `red` if the `last selected` `eventStatus = 2`. How do I display right colors according to eventStatus for every individual event?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        eventData()
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: eventTitleOnc.count, by: 1){
                oncEvents.append(eventTitleOnc[i])}

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: eventTitleOfc.count, by: 1){
        ofcEvents.append(eventTitleOfc[i])
    myEventTableView.reloadData()
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
let myEventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    switch (eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text = oncEvents[indexPath.row]
        break
    case 1:
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text  = ofcEvents[indexPath.row]
        break
default:break
   }
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EventDec> = EventDec.fetchRequest()
    if let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
        results.forEach { (result) in
            if (result.eventStatus == 1)
            {
                myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
            }
            else 
            {
                myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }
  return myEventCell
}

 private func eventData(){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventSchedule")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do
        {
            let results = try context.fetch(request)
            if results.count > 0
            {
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
                {
                    if let eventDisTextOnc = result.value(forKey: "eventNameOnc") as? String
                    {
                        eventTitleOnc.append(eventDisTextOnc)
                    }
                    if let eventDisTextOfc = result.value(forKey: "eventNameOfc") as? String
                    {
                        eventTitleOfc.append(eventDisTextOfc)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

Comment: How you change the `last selected eventStatus`?

Comment: I have an action controller and if the user selects yes, its eventStatus = 1, if no , its eventStatus = 2

Comment: Your code seems fine, can you confirm that `fetchRequest` is updated when the user selected yes/no?

Comment: Yes, I can see in the output

Comment: @Coder221 Doesn't you have already fetch record on `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` ? to append object in ofcEvents and oncEvents array? Because if you loop through in cellForRow method you will get color for only last object.

Comment: OK, I figured out the problem. Check my answer below.

Comment: @Coder221 Then edit your question with that fetch also instead of using two array use array of `EventDec`.

Comment: @NiravD, I did not get what you are telling

Comment: @Coder221 You need to populate data in tableView using single array with type `[EventDec]`, if possible edit your question with fetch request that you are performing in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I am adding my viewDidLoad in my question, but I am not doing any fetch request there, please look at the question

Comment: @Coder221 In `eventData` method you have call fetch request?

Comment: Got it, yes but it is on different entity, but not on EventDec entity

Comment: @Coder221 Then how this entity related to `EventDec` because you want to change textcolor according to eventstatus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137310/discussion-between-coder221-and-nirav-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create array of `EventSchedule` instead of creating two array and use that array with your `cellForRowAt` method.

```
var eventSchedule = [EventSchedule]()
```

Now initialized this array in your eventData method.

```
private func eventData(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventSchedule")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {
        self.eventSchedule = try context.fetch(request) as! [EventSchedule]

    }
    catch{}
}
```

Now use this single array with your `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myEventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    if eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text = self.eventSchedule[indexPath.row]. eventNameOnc
    }
    else {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text  = self.eventSchedule[indexPath.row]. eventNameOfc
    }
    if let eventDesc = self.eventSchedule[indexPath.row].eventDec,           
       let event = eventDesc allObjects.last as? EventDec, event.eventStatus == 1 {
         myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
    else {
         myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the `fetchRequest` in `cellForRowAt` so the color of the `eventLabel` will be set according to the `eventStatus` of the last `result`. You should store the `fetchRequest` as a global variable.

**Solution**:

Declare a global array for storing `EventDec` objects:

```
var events: [EventDec] = []
```

Then, in `eventData()`, insert the data into the array:

```
for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
{
    if let eventDisTextOnc = result.value(forKey: "eventNameOnc") as? String
    {
        eventTitleOnc.append(eventDisTextOnc)
    }
    if let eventDisTextOfc = result.value(forKey: "eventNameOfc") as? String
    {
        eventTitleOfc.append(eventDisTextOfc)
    }

    events.append(result as! EventDec)
}
```

Finally, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the `textColor` corresponding to the `eventStatus` of the event:

```
if (events[indexPath.row].eventStatus == 1)
{
    myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
}
else
{
    myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
}
```

Comment: @Coder221 The code that you did but not working when `fetchRequest` is a global variable.

Comment: I just pasted this in ViewController, outside tableview function   let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EventDec> = EventDec.fetchRequest()

Comment: Can you explain how to make fetch request global, if mine is incorrect

Comment: @Coder221 I have wrote a sample code, please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137322/discussion-between-coder221-and-chengsam).

Answer (score 0):

That's right. The `indexPath.row` isn't matching with your fetch results since it's effectively making a loop inside a loop due to your `forEach` function. The last result of the forEach loop will be the result taken for all the cells. A solution could be making a `cell.tag` for all your cells according to your `eventStatus` and apply the colors from the `cell.tag` value.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation, can you elaborate with some explanation or example that has some code

Comment: I don't have the whole code that you have written, so I can show you a shorter method. Just tweak your fetch request to get the content of that particular cell by matching the name of the event i suppose or any unique identifier and then do the same thing with your if and else statements. `if (result.eventStatus == 1)
            {
                myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
            }
            else 
            {
                myEventCell.eventLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
            }`